# Selenium file upload url "path is not absolute"

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to upload a file to a facebook group with selenium chromedriver.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("http://www.peta.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/goat_2D00_list_2D00_1.jpg")
```

But It throws an Exception Like this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   path is not absolute:

I'm on Windows 10, Chrome 44.0.2403.130, ChromeDriver 2.16.333243, selenium 2.47.1

So how I can upload images from urls ? (without having to explicitly download it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this way you can only upload files *from a local machine*:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("/Path/to/the/file")
```

Download the image first, then upload. For instance:

**With urllib**

```
import os
import urllib

base_dir = "/Path/to/dir/"
path_to_image = os.path.join(base_dir, "upload.jpg")

urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.peta.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/goat_2D00_list_2D00_1.jpg", path_to_image)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(path_to_image)
```

**With requests**

```
import os
import requests

base_dir = "/Path/to/dir/"
path_to_image = os.path.join(base_dir, "upload.jpg")

response = requests.get("http://www.peta.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/goat_2D00_list_2D00_1.jpg")

if response.status_code == 200:
    f = open(base_dir + path_to_image, 'wb')
    f.write(response.content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Sad to hear that's not possible without downloading :( Thanks for your answer. I've edited it to add a requests snippet too, hope u like it !

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while working with C#. Resolved it by copying file into a folder in project, then right click the file and click properties - then change option for copy to output directory to copy always. then you can do this in your steps:

var filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "foldername\filename");

Answer (score -1):

Use the full path like `"C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\hello.jpg"` instead of `"hello.jpg"`.